# How to use mongoose to add new filed in existed collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I search for the mongoose method to add my new field into existed collection,I try the function of findByIdAndUpdate(),but it doesnt work ,are there another method?Please,tell me!

this is my schema code:

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const Schema=mongoose.Schema;

const AccountSchema=new Schema({
    account:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    strick:false
    

});

const Account=mongoose.model('Account',AccountSchema);

module.exports=Account;
```

and application code:

```
  app.post('/api/sendToShoppingCart',async(req,res)=>{
        const db=await mongoose.connect("private");
        const instance=await Account.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.memberID,{
            shoppingCart:Array //new field
        });
        console.log(instance);//it find it
        await instance.save(); //save update

        db.disconnect();//clsoe mongodb
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, My Mongodb cloud didnt increase new field ,and I dont know why it cant work!

Comment: Why would you pass array constructor instead od an array `[]`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I learn this code at another teaching,so I guess it coild work!

Comment: `shoppingCart: []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to define shoppingCart within your schema so it can reflect your changes

```
const AccountSchema = new Schema({
  account: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  strick: false,
  shoppingCart: {
    type: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.Mixed
        }
      ],
      default: [],
  },
});
```

Comment: Is there any method to create new filed without define it in exiested schema?

Comment: yes, sure
you can set strict: false on schema creation .. check this link https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict